# wordpress tool bar is not shown

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

In my wordpress installation I did a lot of testing. One day I tested the Live Composer. (http://livecomposerplugin.com/). But some days a go I decided to do it without a visual composer plugin and deleted the plugin. 
Since that, the admin tool bar on top of my startpage wasn't shown anymore.

I am using the html5blank Theme (http://html5blank.com/

- I tried to add a new admin user and delete the standard user - NO SUCCESS
- I tried to do the steps described in [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21919253/admin-tool-bar-in-wordpress) - NO SUCCESS

Now I don't know, what to do next.

Comment: I have tested it with three browsers. (Firefox, Chrome and Safari) In case it could have something to do with cookies.

Comment: Did you try with: `if ( current_user_can( 'manage_options' ) ) {
 add_filter( 'show_admin_bar', '__return_true' , 1000 );
}`

Comment: Dear dingo_d. Thank you very much. I pasted your line into my functions.php in my theme folder. I cleared the cache and now it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so you can try adding in your `functions.php`

```
if ( current_user_can( 'manage_options' ) ) { 
    add_filter( 'show_admin_bar', '__return_true' , 1000 ); 
}
```

This should force admin bar on logged in users (users with enough privilege that is).

Hope this helps :)